# Armadillo integer eigen decomposition

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I am trying to use Armadillo to decompose a matrix consisting of integers (i.e. `arma::Mat<int>`) into eigenvalues and eigenvectors 
However, it always gives me compile error no matter what I put as input matrix and output vector/matrix type 
It works when i declare the input matrix as `arma::Mat<double>`, output vector(eigenvalues) as `arma::Col<std::complex<double>>` and output matrix(eigenvectors) as `arma::Mat<std::complex<double>>` 
I have tried using `int` and/or `std::complex<int>` as types for the inputs and the outputs but neither of them worked. 
Is there a way that I can do decompose matrices of integer values? 
Thanks

Comment: @kylecorver if I use `std::complex<int>` as type I get `unsupported type` and `mismatched types` <br> if I use `int` I get `arma::Col<int> is not derived from arma::Col<std::complex<_Tp> >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the integer matrix to a double matrix using the [conv_to](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to) function. For example, `imat A = ...; mat B = conv_to<mat>::from(A);`.  Then you can do eigen decomposition on the converted matrix.

Comment: do I absolutely have to convert? Is there anyway to do this without converting to double?

Comment: Armadillo uses LAPACK (or equivalent library such as Intel MKL) for eigen decomposition.  LAPACK doesn't support integer matrices.